# Help installing C++ for Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, mingw

I am trying to install c++ for netbeans.. I tried installing the cygwin and mingw but i can't compile because the make file that comes with Mingw is incompatible ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [these](http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html) Instructions from the Netbeans Website